# Confusion with generating unit vectors

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I have some difficulty interpreting this section of my lecture notes:

[image]

My question is with $(2.8)$.

How does $$\frac{cos \ \phi \ \vec i + sin \ \phi \ \vec j}{||cos \ \phi \vec i + sin \ \phi \ \vec j||}=cos \ \phi \ \vec i + sin \ \phi \ \vec j$$

hold true? I believe $||cos \ \phi \vec i + sin \ \phi \ \vec j||$ represents a number, as it is a magnitude. My thinking was, if it's a unit vector, that means the magnitude is $1$ and thus we have the numerator as the solution. But then, I run into an issue with:

$$\frac{-Rsin \ \phi \ \vec i + Rcos \ \phi \ \vec j}{||-Rsin \ \phi \ \vec i + Rcos \ \phi \ \vec j||}= -sin\ \phi \ \vec i + cos \ \phi \ \vec j$$

If the denominator is $1$, then the numerator and solution are not the same, which means my understanding is wrong. How did these right hand sides be reached?

Comment: The denominator is equal to $R$.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ are a bit special--they will always be magnitude 1, since we have the identity $(\cos\theta)^2+(\sin\theta)^2=1$.

If you take a vector of the form $\mathbf{x}=(R\cos \theta, R\sin \theta)$, the magnitude will be $R$, since $$|\mathbf{x}|=\sqrt{(R\cos\theta)^2+(R\sin\theta)^2}=\sqrt{R^2((\cos\theta)^2+(\sin\theta)^2)}=R\sqrt{1}=R.$$

Comment: Oh - so my guess was right. Like, I knew that but...the denominator's magnitude would be $R$, then, would it not?

Comment: Gah! And that means we can divide everything through by $R$ and arrive to the correct RHS! I'm with you.

Comment: Why, then, is $\frac{k}{||k||} = k$? Is $||k||$ necessarily $1$?

Comment: Generally, it is not true that $\frac{k}{\|k\|}=k$. It is only true when $k$ is already a unit vector (in the example they give, it is)

Comment: Ah, so since $k$ is a unit vector, $||k|| = 1$ by definition, then?

Comment: Oh, oops, yes! A unit vector, by definition, has length one. (I didn't realize you were referring to the unit basis vector $\mathbf{k}$, not some arbitrary vector)